# MongoDB Atlas Search Stage for newsfeed with GoogleRating, CurrentDate, LikeCount & CommentCount

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm working on social media platform and I need to fetch posts for newsfeed with mongodb search query.

currently I'm using dynamic index on my post collection, Let say this my post collection

```
{
 _id : ObjectId('123'),
 GoogleRating : 4.5,
 LikeCount : 20,
 CommentCount : 10,
 CreatedDate : "2022-04-21T00:00:00.000+00:00"
},
{
 _id : ObjectId('456'),
 GoogleRating : 1,
 LikeCount : 0,
 CommentCount : 5,
 CreatedDate : "2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"
}
```

And this is my current search stage

```
"$search":{
   "compound":{
      "should":[
         {
            "near":{
               "path":"GoogleRating",
               "origin":5,
               "pivot":2,
               "score":{
                  "boost":{
                     "value":2
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "near":{
               "path":"CreatedDate",
               "origin":ISODate("2022-04-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
               "pivot":7776000000,
               "score":{
                  "boost":{
                     "value":3
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "near":{
               "path":"LikeCount",
               "origin":1000,
               "pivot":2,
               "score":{
                  "boost":{
                     "value":3
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "near":{
               "path":"CommentCount",
               "origin":1000,
               "pivot":2,
               "score":{
                  "boost":{
                     "value":3
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I've three criteria to boost document score.

1. Boost score on the basis of GoogleRating.
2. Boost score on the basis of Current date.
3. Boost score on the basis of LikeCount and CommentCount.

I need to improve my search result Because it's not giving me desired output please suggest me what should i need to change in my search stage.

Comment: What order would you like it to be in?

Comment: Google Rating is max set to 5 se in that case this near operator is working fine. but in LikeCount and CommentCount we don't know exactly what is the highest point we need to increase score on the basis of like and comment count. 
And CreatedDate should be the priority to achieve recency with relevance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. Normally, there would be an input that represents the query that you want to be relevant, but it's not required. For that reason, I will use a wildcard query on a wildcard path (IOW, everything matches).

We do, however, expose functionality for surfacing documents based on field values as you have expressed a desire for in your question. It's called [function scores](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/scoring/#std-label-function-score-expression). Using the query you supplied, I made one modification to date and things seem to be working just fine and returning in the order listed above. Let me know if the below works for you. Here's the NodeJS:

```
[
  {
    '$search': {
      'compound': {
        'should': [
          {
            'near': {
              'path': 'GoogleRating', 
              'origin': 5, 
              'pivot': 2, 
              'score': {
                'boost': {
                  'value': 2
                }
              }
            }
          }, {
            'near': {
              'path': 'CreatedDate', 
              'origin': new Date('Thu, 21 Apr 2022 00:00:00 GMT'), 
              'pivot': 7776000000, 
              'score': {
                'boost': {
                  'value': 3
                }
              }
            }
          }, {
            'near': {
              'path': 'LikeCount', 
              'origin': 1000, 
              'pivot': 2, 
              'score': {
                'boost': {
                  'value': 9
                }
              }
            }
          }, {
            'near': {
              'path': 'CommentCount', 
              'origin': 1000, 
              'pivot': 2, 
              'score': {
                'boost': {
                  'value': 10
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I've updated my code and currently working with search query in MongoDB Compass so this is not the case.
I need to add the Like And Comment count to the score so all those posts which have more engagements of user comes first in the result.